# Browser Pop-up WIndows and Silverlight OOB

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-oob

Within the browser I can use this to open a pop-up window:

```
 System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri(uri), "_blank");
```

How do I do this when running outside of the browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an OOB app, you can use the following work around:

Create a derived hyperlink button like this:

```
public class MyHyperlinkButton : HyperlinkButton 
{ 
        public void ClickMe() 
        { 
                base.OnClick(); 
        } 
}
```

Use that for navigation:

```
private void NavigateToUri(Uri url) 
{ 
        if (App.Current.IsRunningOutOfBrowser) 
        { 
                MyHyperlinkButton button = new MyHyperlinkButton(); 
                button.NavigateUri = url; 
                button.TargetName = "_blank"; 
                button.ClickMe(); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
                System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(url, "_blank"); 
        } 
}
```

[see forums.silverlight.net](http://forums.silverlight.net/p/216226/513215.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You don't. System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage is a call to the HtmlPage that is hosting the silverlight application. In out of Browser, you are not hosted by a web page. Trying to do that just hangs the application.

If you have elevated privileges, than you could make an OS call to open a new browser, or I'm sure there are 3rd party controls that act as a hosted browser.

Comment: I'm not against using elevated privileges. What's the OS call I need to use?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is through ShellExecute:

```
if (App.Current.IsRunningOutOfBrowser)  
{ 
    dynamic shell = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("Shell.Application");
    shell.ShellExecute("someURL", "", "", "open", 1);
}
```

Documentation for ShellExecute is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774148(VS.85).aspx